# Looking for libconfig java wrapper

Tags: java, c++, wrapper, libconfig

currently I'm working on a java webapplication development and it require me to parse this libconfig file http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/ .

But I can't find any compatible library in Java to parse libconfig file.

Any idea? And worst case have to write my own wrapper for it?

Comment: I add a comment because who is searching for a solution often arrive to this page. A Java wrapper is this: https://github.com/willyborankin/libconfig